# How to change background color on highlight effect?

Tags: jquery

I hava a jquery mobile slider.

```
<input name="slider-1" id="slider-1" data-highlight="true"min="0" 
                                            max="100" value="50" type="range">
```

I want to change the color of the highlight fill on the track of the slider? (By default its blue ).
this is my code but its not work

```
$("#slider-1").effect("highlight", { color: "#ff00ff" }, 3000);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong selector to change the default color of the slider.

**`div.ui-btn-active`** this is right one

```
div.ui-btn-active{
    background: #ff00ff;
}
```

Using jQuery,

```
$("div.ui-btn-active").css("background","#ff00ff");
```

[image]

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3CRm9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the CSS solution is better:

```
#slider-3::selection
{
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}

#slider-3::-moz-selection   /* firefox*/
{
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your color code in this css class and dont change class name.

```
.ui-btn-active {
   background: linear-gradient(#5393C5, #6FACD5) repeat scroll 0 0 #5393C5;
   border: 1px solid #2373A5;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #3373A5;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.css` property for it and want to change background with animation use the `animate` function.

```
 $("#slider-3").css("background-color","#ff00ff");
```

jQuery [`.css Documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Happened by mistake, reverted